# Why I'm getting the error while passing props to a child component react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, undefined

**While passing an array to the child component via setState hook I'm getting an error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map'), even though Categories is an array. The point is that I'm passing props through another child component. But still the error seems odd**

**

```js
---------------------------
Parent component:
---------------------------

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Categories from "./Categories";
import Products from "./Products";

const ShopPage = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(Categories);
 <>
        <Products products={data} />
 </>
  );
};

export default ShopPage;

---------------------------
Products component:
---------------------------


import Product from "./Product";

const Products = ({ products }) => {
  // console.log(products);
  return (
    <>
      <Product products={products} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Products;
---------------------------
Product component:
---------------------------


const Product = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div >
      {products.map((value) => {
        const { id, title } = value;
        return (
          <>
            <div
              className={styles.item}
              key={id}
            >
              <h1>{title}</h1>
          </>
          )
     <div>
     
export default Product;
```

**

Comment: Can you show us the Categories file? You say it's an array, but the error says otherwise.

Comment: const Categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Men's black cap",
    price: 2,
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed",
    category: "Cap"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Women's blue cap",
    price: 25,
    description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed",
    category: "Cap"
  }
];

export default Categories;

Comment: I'm calling setData inside shopPage component, like so: const [data, setData] = useState(Categories);

  // const style = hovered
  //   ? { backgroundColor: "#ffcbcb", color: "#fff", transition: "all 0.5s ease" }
  //   : {};
  const filterResult = (catItem) => {
    const result = Categories.filter((curData) => curData.category === catItem);

    setData(result);
  };

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moon-djocul?file=/src/components/ShopPage.js:240-556

Comment: That sandbox is rendering a `<Products />` in App.js. You're not passing a products prop in at all. The `ShopPage` component is irrelevant, since you never render it.